# Creating Subscription using cashier in stripe return No such price: 'prod_L1SZUHkXQUDIKY'

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, subscription, laravel-cashier

I am creating a stripe subscription with Laravel cashier but unable to create the subscription, it's throwing the error no such price found, my product is created in the stripe and I am getting it from blade and passing to newScription method.

My Controller Code

**Customer is creating but subscription is not creating**

```
 $stripeCustomer = null;
 if (is_null($user->stripe_id)) 
 {
   $stripeCustomer = $user->createAsStripeCustomer();
 }

 $user->newSubscription('test', $request->plan)
   ->create($paymentMethod, ['email' => $user->email]);

// $request->plan = it's returning this product prod_L1SZUHkXQUDIKY
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Subscription object with Stripe, you need to pass a [Price object](https://site-admin.stripe.com/docs/api/prices) (`price_xxx`). In the example you've shared, you're passing a Product object.

Products can have multiple prices. For example, you might have a single recurring service you offer but have both a monthly and an annual price. You can learn more about this on Stripe's [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide).

Comment: can you please send me the exact piece of code to subscribe a user. I am adding the price array instead of product object and it's throwing the error The `price` parameter should be the ID of a price object, rather than the literal numerical price

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel Cashier, but looking at their documentation I assume you'll need something like: `newSubscription('test', 'price_xxx')->create($paymentMethod, ['email' => $user->email])`.

Where `price_xxx` is the ID of the Stripe Price object you want to subscribe to.

Answer (score 0):

My payment method is returning null, that's why it's throwing this error.
when I passed the payment object then it worked

```
$user = Auth::user();
$paymentMethod = $request->payment_method;
$user->addPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);
$plan = $request->plan;
$plan = json_decode($plan);

$user->newSubscription($plan->name, $plan->plan_id)->create($paymentMethod, [
    'email' => $user->email,
   ]);
```

user email is optional stuff